Maven dependency tree has older version than what is the transitive dependency pom of dependent library
I have a maven project which uses spring-kafka. If I run mvn dependency:tree I get:
....
[INFO] +- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:6.1.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:6.1.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:2.0.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:3.7.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:jar:1.5.6-3:runtime
[INFO] |     +- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.8.0:runtime
[INFO] |     \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.10.5:runtime
....

This shows kafka-clients version 3.7.1.
If I look at the pom.xml of spring-kafka:3.3.0 it shows version 3.8.1 as a dependency:
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

So why is  version 3.7.1 pulled in? I can provide the whole dependency:tree output.
There are only 2 dependencies which have kafka-clients as a transient: spring-kafka and spring-kafka-test.
Both pull in 3.7.1 but yet have 3.8.1 as dependency versions in their pom.xml.
I've run mvn clean install -U, dependency:resolve -U and tried many other updates.
I've tried explicitly setting 3.8.1 as a dependency in my project but then there is a NoSuchMethodException due to a seeming library mismatch on KafkaUtils.
Help me understand why maven is pulling in the older dependency instead of what is defined in the dependent's pom.xml files.

Please show your full pom file.

You are using Spring Boot which manages it, not the spring-kafka module. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v3.3.0/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/build.gradle#L960 . Depending on which Spring Boot version (assuming something in the 3.3 range) you are already messing around with dependency versions leading to incompatible versions (as Spring BOot is tied to certain versions). If you want to use newer ones you will need to upgrade Spring BOot.

I recommend to use Spring Boot 3.4.0 (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v3.4.0/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/build.gradle#L960)

I should have mentioned earlier, I've tried Springboot's latest from 3.3.4 to 3.3.6. It always references kafka-clients 3.7.1.

Which is the version used by SPring BOot 3.3.x (as stated before). Spring Boot 3.4 upgraded to 3.8 as well as to spring-kafka 3.3 (which you shoehorned into Spring Boot 3.3 which is using spring-kafka 3.2).

Spring Boot is a huge project that integrates with tons of other projects and ensuring that all of these different projects are on compatible versions that can run with each other is not a trivial task. To combat this the Spring Boot teams maintain a BOM that specifies version of other projects that they have validated work with each version of Spring Boot. They document every dependency they manage on their site: Managed Coordinates. For many dependencies, versions other than the one specified in the Spring BOM will be compatible but in general it is a best practice to let the Spring BOM manage as many versions as possible. To let the Spring BOM manage a version for you, you can request a group:artifact with the version omitted and the default version in the BOM will be used.
In your specific case, if we look through Spring Boot's documentation we see that the 3.3.x line of Spring Boot uses the 3.7.x line of Kafka while the 3.4.x line of Spring Boot uses the 3.8.x line of Kafka by default. The best way to get the new version of Kafka would be to move to Spring Boot 3.4.x to ensure it is compatible.

This is the most clear answer and explains best what the issue is. I updated my pom and removed all explicit versions which are already defined in the springboot pom in your link and now my project loads the 3.8.1 kafka libs as well as other required libraries and there are no conflicts.
Just as a side note: the reason we initially started setting explicit versions was due to code scanning tools blocking our builds due to certain library versions.
Thanks all for your help.

The project I work on have strict policies regarding library versions with CVEs as well. The practice I have found works the best for us when a new CVE comes in is first checking to see if there is a new version of Spring Boot that brings in a fixed version of the library by default. If there is, we try our best to move to the new version of Spring Boot. If one does not yet exist or there is a reason we cant move yet, we pin to the new version of the library and leave a comment stating that the dependency is managed by Spring and the pin should be removed once we are on the appropriate version
